# More advanced power supply circuits

Tags: power-supply

I'm currently learning about power supply circuits (mostly because I want to make my own to power an LED strip). Everywhere I search I find the same basic principle:

Transformer -> Rectifier -> Filter -> Regulator -> Load

So my first question is: do these building blocks ever change? Are there some appliances where these are not enough? To me it just seems rather too simple.

Next there are some circuits that follow the plan above, like this one (taken from https://www.build-electronic-circuits.com/power-supply-circuit/):
[image: simple power supply circuit]

So if I'm following the plan above, can this be made more advanced? Or is it enough for most applications?

Comment: This would be a linear type power supply.  They can be inefficient because all the voltage dropped in the regulator is turned into heat.  Look into switch-mode power supplies and you will find a whole new world.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you show an example of is the classic "linear power supply".

It is:

- fine for low output currents
- easy to build for beginners
- easy to understand

But it is not good:

- for high output currents
- if you want a small product, the transformer can be quite large
- as the transformer is relatively expensive

> do these building blocks ever change?

How do you mean? If I need 12 V instead of 5 V then I'd use an LM7812 and a different transformer, maybe the capacitors need a higher voltage rating. But the schematic will remain the same.

There are of course other topologies, your phone charger uses a different design as 
it needs to be cheap, small and effcient. For such a supply a [flyback converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyback_converter) is used. On [this site](https://www.dos4ever.com/flyback/flyback.html) you can find a hobbyist level example.

Answer (score 1):

More advanced?

Most modern power supplies are SMPS (switched mode power supply). The transformer can be made much smaller if the frequency of the signal is much higher.

[image]

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Switched-mode_power_supply

Comment: You can get the best of both SMPS and linear (for a number of extra components): See https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/lt-journal-article/LTJournal-V24N2-2014-07.pdf (Look in the design features section)

Answer (score 0):

Power supply circuits can vary drastically depends on what's the source and whats the voltage, current and power needed by the load.  Let me illustrate few examples.

For the xenon flash lamp used for cameras, power level is at Kilowatts and the power is supplied by a harmless relatively small battery at 3V to 12V. So how it works?

Between the battery and the xenon tube there is a special power supply circuitry which boost up the low voltage to up to 400V and store it in a capacitor. At the moment trigger signal is received, all energy stored in the cap is dumped into the tube in miliSeconds. Since power is defined as the rate at which energy is converted, plugging the numbers into the equation reveal Kilowatts. Current involve in the load circuit reach up to 50Amps!

Another example is 'joule thief' circuitry. In this system, intermittently pulsating electric energy such as from a piezo crystals or magnetic pickups are harvested and accumulated in a capacitor, regulated and delivered to loads.

In these two examples i give here, the topology is way too different than classical blocks you mentioned.